# Como entender las condiciones en cosntructores

Tags: java, poo, java-8

Estoy realizando un ejercicio pero no logro entender bien la lógica del punto de validar los caracteres

Clase telefono

```
public class Telefono {

// Atributos
private String nombre;
private String tipo;
private String estado;

// Constructor
public  String Telefono(String nombre, String tipo) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;


    if (this.getNombre() != null && this.getTipo() != null)
        if (this.tipo.equals("movil") && this.tipo.equals("convencional")) {
            return this.tipo = "e";
                    
                } else {

            return this.tipo = "C";
        }
    return tipo;

}
// Getters & Setters

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

}
```

Clase Main

```
package com.cmc.test;

import com.cmc.entidades.Telefono;

public class TestTelefono {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Telefono telefono1=new Telefono("0992920306", "convencional");
    System.out.println("telefono 1: "+telefono1.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono2=new Telefono("0992920306", "MOVIL");
    System.out.println("  telefono 2: "+telefono2.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono3=new Telefono("0992920306", "Movil");
    System.out.println("    telefono 3: "+telefono3.getEstado());

    Telefono telefono4=new Telefono("2375467", "CONVENCIONAL");
    System.out.println("     telefono 4: "+telefono4.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono5=new Telefono("0992920306",null);
    System.out.println("telefono 5: "+telefono5.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono6=new Telefono(null,"Convencional");
    System.out.println("  telefono 6: "+telefono6.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono7=new Telefono(null,"Convencional");
    System.out.println("    telefono7: "+telefono7.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono8=new Telefono("2387991","convencional");
    System.out.println("      telefono8: "+telefono8.getEstado());

    Telefono telefono9=new Telefono("2387991","Fijo");
    System.out.println("telefono9: "+telefono9.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono10=new Telefono("2222222","CoNvEnCiOnAL");
    System.out.println("   telefono10: "+telefono10.getEstado());
    
}
}
```

Debo realizar la siguiente condición en constructor

Agregar un constructor que reciba el número y el tipo y ejecute la siguiente lógica:
Asigna los valores de número y tipo a los atributos respectivos.
Dependiendo de las validaciones que realice, colocará el valor de estado:
C : Si es correcto
E : Si tiene error

Para determinar si es correcto o no el teléfono, se debe cumplir las siguientes condiciones:

1. Tanto el teléfono como el tipo deben ser diferentes de null, si
   alguno es null, se considera con error
2. Los tipos pueden ser Movil o Convencional, si es un tipo diferente,
   se considera con error.
3. Si el tipo es Movil, el teléfono debe tener 10 caracteres, si es
   convencional, debe tener 7 caracteres. Validar únicamente la
   longitud, no el contenido de la cadena. La longitud de un String se
   obtiene con el método length()

**El resultado esperado en la clase test:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta pregunta es la misma que [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/440654/porque-me-duplica-el-resultado-la-condicion-del-constructor) otra que ya hiciste?. Igualmente si quieres saber por que se incluye una validación en el constructor eso depende de del diseño del programa y la necesidad específica.  En tu caso es parte del ejercicio para saber si hiciste bien las validaciones.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Porque me duplica el resultado la condicion del constructor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/440654/porque-me-duplica-el-resultado-la-condicion-del-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente estas tratando de usar el constructor para inicializar, pero el constructor no debe tener ningún tipo de retorno, si tiene un valor de retorno esto sería un método

```
public  String Telefono(String nombre, String tipo) {
   ...
   ...
   ...
    return tipo;
}
```

Para que sea un constructor debería tener esta forma y dentro tendría las validaciones pero no retornaría ningún tipo.

```
// Constructor
public Telefono(String telefono, String tipo) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.tipo = tipo;

    if (this.telefono != null && this.tipo != null) {
        //*** Movil, el teléfono debe tener 10 caracteres.  
        if (this.tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("movil") && this.telefono.length() == 10) {
            this.estado = "C"; //Correcto                   
            //*** convencional, el teléfono debe tener 7 caracteres.            
        } else if (this.tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("convencional") && this.telefono.length() == 7) {
            this.estado = "C";
        } else {                
            //Los tipos pueden ser Movil o Convencional, si es un tipo diferente, se considera con error.
            this.estado = "E";
        }
    }else{
            this.estado = "E";//Tanto el teléfono como el tipo deben ser diferentes de null, si alguno es null, se considera con error 
    }
}
```

Es demasiado importante revisar como funcionan los [operadores lógicos en Java](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-6957/chp-typeopexpr/index.html) y revisar la función [equalsIgnoreCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) para que puedas implementar la lògica que deseas, como lo indicas la longitud de un String se obtiene con el método `length()`.

La clase completa serìa:

```
public class Telefono {

    // Atributos
    private String telefono;
    private String tipo;
    private String estado;


    // Constructor
    public Telefono(String telefono, String tipo) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.tipo = tipo;

        if (this.telefono != null && this.tipo != null) {
            //*** Movil, el teléfono debe tener 10 caracteres.  
            if (this.tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("movil") && this.telefono.length() == 10) {
                this.estado = "C"; //Correcto                   
                //*** convencional, el teléfono debe tener 7 caracteres.            
            } else if (this.tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("convencional") && this.telefono.length() == 7) {
                this.estado = "C";
            } else {                
                //Los tipos pueden ser Movil o Convencional, si es un tipo diferente, se considera con error.
                this.estado = "E";
            }
        }else{
                this.estado = "E";//Tanto el teléfono como el tipo deben ser diferentes de null, si alguno es null, se considera con error 
        }
    }

    // Getters & Setters
    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

}
```

de acuerdo a la clase `TestTelefono` la salida serìa:

```
telefono 1: E
  telefono 2: C
    telefono 3: C
     telefono 4: C
telefono 5: E
  telefono 6: E
    telefono7: E
      telefono8: C
telefono9: E
   telefono10: C
```