# Porque me duplica el resultado la condicion del constructor

Tags: java, poo, java-8

Tengo una duda, porque me duplica la letra en el resultado del constructor

Mi clase Telefono

```
public class Telefono {

// Atributos
private String nombre;
private String tipo;
private String estado;

// Constructor
public Telefono(String nombre, String tipo) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.tipo = tipo;
    

    if (this.nombre != null && this.tipo != null && this.tipo.equals("movil") == this.tipo.equals("convencional")) {
        String activo = this.estado = "C";
        System.out.println(activo);
    } else {
        String desactivado = this.estado = "E";
        System.out.println(desactivado);
    }

}

public Telefono() {

}

// Getters & Setters

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

}
```

Mi clase Main

```
public class TestTelefono {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Telefono telefono1=new Telefono("0992920306", "convencional");
    System.out.println("telefono 1: "+telefono1.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono2=new Telefono("0992920306", "MOVIL");
    System.out.println("  telefono 2: "+telefono2.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono3=new Telefono("0992920306", "Movil");
    System.out.println("    telefono 3: "+telefono3.getEstado());

    Telefono telefono4=new Telefono("2375467", "CONVENCIONAL");
    System.out.println("     telefono 4: "+telefono4.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono5=new Telefono("0992920306",null);
    System.out.println("telefono 5: "+telefono5.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono6=new Telefono(null,"Convencional");
    System.out.println("  telefono 6: "+telefono6.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono7=new Telefono(null,"Convencional");
    System.out.println("    telefono7: "+telefono7.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono8=new Telefono("2387991","convencional");
    System.out.println("      telefono8: "+telefono8.getEstado());

    Telefono telefono9=new Telefono("2387991","Fijo");
    System.out.println("telefono9: "+telefono9.getEstado());
    
    Telefono telefono10=new Telefono("2222222","CoNvEnCiOnAL");
    System.out.println("   telefono10: "+telefono10.getEstado());
    
}
}
```

El resultado que me brinda es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado esperado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LO SOLICITADO ES:

Agregar un constructor que reciba el número y el tipo y ejecute la siguiente lógica:
Asigna los valores de número y tipo a los atributos respectivos.
Dependiendo de las validaciones que realice, colocará el valor de estado:
C : Si es correcto
E : Si tiene error
Para determinar si es correcto o no el teléfono, se debe cumplir las siguientes condiciones:

1. Tanto el teléfono como el tipo deben ser diferentes de null, si
   alguno es null, se considera con error
2. Los tipos pueden ser Movil o Convencional, si es un tipo diferente,
   se considera con error.
3. Si el tipo es Movil, el teléfono debe tener 10 caracteres, si es
   convencional, debe tener 7 caracteres. Validar únicamente la
   longitud, no el contenido de la cadena. La longitud de un String se
   obtiene con el método length()

Comment: ¿Qué se supone que hace esta parte del `if`? `&& this.tipo.equals("movil") == this.tipo.equals("convencional")`.  Además, ¿por qué imprimes en el constructor?

Comment: Segun el ejercicio menciona que debo realizar la comparacion de que si es movil o convencional me retorne como correcto, de lo contrario me lo retornara inxorrecto, y la forma en la que imprimo es porque no se como usar para distinguir entre correcto e incorrecto

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente, la lógica para determinar el `estado` no debe ir en el constructor, sino que deberías implementar la lógica para determinar el estado en un método propio (vamos a llamarle `setEstado()`). Ese método deberá ser llamado tanto desde el constructor, como desde cualquiera de los setters que modifiquen propiedades de la clase que alterían el estado (gracias @Benito-B por tu importantísimo comentario).

Así, cuando alguna de las propiedades cambie, la lógica de `setEstado()` establecerá esa propiedad conforme a la información real del objeto.

Por otra parte, la lógica que estabas aplicando era errónea e incompleta.

Aquí he hecho dos grupos de verificaciones para determinar que el estado es `C`. Por un lado, verifico que `nombre` y `tipo` no sean nulos:

```
( this.nombre != null && this.tipo != null )
```

Y por otro verifico que `tipo` sea igual a `movil` y que tenga `10` caracteres,

```
this.tipo.toLowerCase().equals("movil") && this.nombre.length()==10
```

O que sea igual a `convencional` y que tenga `7` caracteres:

```
this.tipo.toLowerCase().equals("convencional") && this.nombre.length()==7
```

He usado además `toLowerCase()` para que valide tanto `MOVIL`  como `movil`, etc.

Esta sería la clase completa con todos los cambios:

```
public class Telefono 
{

    // Atributos
    private String nombre;
    private String tipo;
    private String estado;

    // Constructor
    public Telefono(String nombre, String tipo) 
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        setEstado();
    }

    public String getNombre() 
    {
        return nombre;
    }

    public String getTipo() 
    {
        return tipo;
    }    
    
    public String getEstado() 
    {  
        return estado;
    }
 
    public void setNombre(String nombre)
    {
        this.nombre=nombre;
        setEstado();
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo)
    {
        this.tipo=tipo;
        setEstado();
    }      
    
    private void setEstado()
    {
        if (     ( this.nombre != null && this.tipo != null ) 
              && ( this.tipo.toLowerCase().equals("movil") && this.nombre.length()==10 || this.tipo.toLowerCase().equals("convencional") && this.nombre.length()==7 )
           ) 
        {
            this.estado = "C";
        }
        else
        {
             this.estado = "E";
        }          
    }
}
```

La salida será la esperada:

```
telefono 1: E
  telefono 2: C
    telefono 3: C
     telefono 4: C
telefono 5: E
  telefono 6: E
    telefono7: E
      telefono8: C
telefono9: E
   telefono10: C
```

Comment: Técnicamente, la lógica para *setear* el estado no debería ir en los setter?? Debería tener un `private setEstado(){...}` o `actualizarEstado()` que se llama desde los setters de nombre y tipo además de en el constructor, y `getEstado()` solo se encargaría de devolver dicho estado, que se mantendrá actualizado cada vez que se cambie algo del teléfono, sin necesidad de llamar a `getEstado`

Comment: Tienes toda la razón @Benito-B. Ahora edito.